# Cannot Send App for Review in Google Play Console

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

Cannot send app for review in google play console. On the Publishing overview page, it says "To send changes for review, complete the required steps on the Dashboard."  But in the dashboard I completed all required steps.

Comment: How did you solve this? I'm in the same situation

Comment: I'am deleted app and readded again to console

Answer (score 1):

In my case (as suggested promptly by the Google's support), the issue was I had to complete also the "Test your app with a larger group of testers that you control" block of tasks, in the dashboard.